# How to get my Discord bot to add/remove items from a text file

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, discord.py

My script uses BeautifulSoup to scrape information from webpages that are listed in a text file. I want to create a discord bot that will allow me to set up 2 commands.

`+add <url>` will add the url to the bottom of the list in the text file.

`+remove <url>` will remove the url from the message from the text file.

I have created a discord bot, it connects but I have no idea how to go about setting up the command to add/remove from a text file.

```
import requests
import lxml.html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from dhooks import Webhook, Embed
import random
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from threading import Thread

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '+')

ua = UserAgent()
header = {'User-Agent':ua.chrome}

# Proxies
proxy_list = []

for line in open('proxies.txt', 'r'):
    line = line.replace('\n', '')
    proxy_list.append(line)

def get_proxy():
    proxy = random.choice(proxy_list)
    proxies = {
        "http": f'{str(proxy)}',
        "https": f'{str(proxy)}'
    }
    return proxies

# Opening URL file 
def loop():
    with open('urls.txt','r') as file:
        url_list = file.readlines()
    pos = 0
    while True:
        if pos >= len(url_list):
            pos = 0
        url = url_list[pos]
        pos += 1
        proxies = get_proxy()
        result = requests.get(url.strip() ,headers=header,timeout=6,proxies=proxies)
        #src = result.content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(result.content, 'lxml')

        # Finding elements within a webpage
        titles = soup.title
        price = soup.find_all('span',attrs={'class':'prodPriceCont valuteCont pricetext'})
        rated = soup.find_all('span',attrs={'class':'rateB'})
        addToCarts = soup.find_all('a',attrs={'id':'btnAddToCart'})
        imageURL = soup.find_all('a',attrs={'class':'prodImg max'})
        brands = soup.find_all('strong',attrs={'itemprop':'brand'})
        
        for title in titles:
            ItemTitle = titles.string
            #print(ItemTitle)
        
        for span in price:
            ItemPrice = span.string
            #print(ItemPrice)
        
        for rate in rated:
            rating = rate.string+"/5.00"
            #print(rating)
        
        for carts in addToCarts:
            inStock = carts.string
            #print(inStock)
        
        for URL in imageURL:
            imgURL = URL['href']
            #print(imgURL)
        
        for brand in brands:
            productBrand = brand.string
            #print(productBrand)

        # Discord Embed Setup   
        hook = Webhook("WEBHOOK")

        embed = Embed(
            description=ItemTitle,
            color=0x0d0d22,
            timestamp='now'  # sets the timestamp to current time
            )

        embed.set_author(name=productBrand)
        embed.add_field(name='Price', value=ItemPrice, inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name='Rating', value=rating, inline=True)
        embed.set_footer(text='Test', icon_url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/628005829840470037/8286685de0f2d7d94d94e020caf3265d.png?size=128')

        embed.set_thumbnail(imgURL)

        hook.send(embed=embed)

        print(ItemTitle+" | "+ItemPrice+" | "+rating+" | Item has been checked")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is online!")
    a = Thread(target=loop, args=())
    a.start()

client.run('TOKEN')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you could setup your add and remove commands:

```
@bot.command()
async def add(ctx, args):
  url_to_add = args.lower() + '\n'

  with open('text.txt', 'a') as url_file:
    url_file.write(url_to_add)
```

The add command is pretty simple. First we format the url sent in by the user to make sure nothing breaks when we search for it. Next we open the text file in append mode (meaning we are modifying/adding text to the file). Finally we just write the url to the file. Thats it for the add command.

```
@bot.command()
async def remove(ctx, args):
  url_to_remove = args.lower() + '\n'

  with open("text.txt", 'r') as url_file:
    urls = url_file.readlines()

  replacement_urls = [url for url in urls if url_to_remove not in url]

  with open('text.txt', 'w') as url_file:
    url_file.truncate()
    url_file.write(''.join(replacement_urls))
```

The remove command is a little more complicated but easy nonetheless. First we again format the url provided by the user so it matches the way we stored it in the file. Next, we open the file in read mode and store the contents of the files in a list called 'urls'. Then we use list comprehension to create a new list of urls that include every url from the file except the one being removed. We then open the text file in write mode, erase the contents, and then write all of the original urls (except the one we removed) back into the file as a string.

DISCLAIMER: This is not the most efficient way to do this. This method will throw an error if the text file size is greater than the RAM memory available on the machine the bot is hosted on. However, if you do not plan on having a huge text file this is the easiest way to accomplish your task.

Comment: Okay the add command worked. But the remove command throws this error - `replacement_urls = [url for url in urls if url != x]
NameError: name 'x' is not defined`

Comment: @Lukemul69 yeah sorry I accidentally forgot to redefine a var after testing. I have edited the answer to make the code work.

Comment: I changed it thanks. I ran the code and I do not get any errors however it did not remove anything from the text file.

Comment: My mistake, it just doesnt remove items from the beginning or the end of the list.

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean. Can you explain that a little more?

Comment: I have 10 urls on the list, when I use the remove command I can remove urls 2-9, it will not remove url 1 or url 10.

Comment: I edited the answer to define the replacement urls in a different way: `replacement_urls = [url for url in urls if url_to_remove not in url]` It should work now.

Comment: I tried the code and its works perfectly for me. Could you provide the data you are using with the bot so I can try and debug from there?